# Processing Jquery Ajax form submit with php

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

Recently I've been struggling with Jquery and Ajax while trying to submit forms with them.  I have a very simple form with a username field and password field as well as a submit button.  What the form is supposed to do is that once the form is submitted the info would be sent by Ajax to a php file which then adds the said form values to a database.  What I am struggling with is how to get the values from Ajax to php.  Here is my code:

```
$('#form').submit(function(){

var username = $('#username').val();
var password = $('#password').val();

var dataString = 'uname=' + username + '&passw=' + password;


$.ajax({

    type: "POST",
    url:'check.php',
    data: dataString,

    success: function(data){
        alert(data);//only for testing purposes
    }
});
```

What eludes me is how can I get the dataString from this with php?

Comment: `$_POST['uname']` in `check.php` did not work?

Comment: @AndriusNaruševičius I tested it by changing the .submit to .blur in order to monitor it all realtime and when I tried to $_POST['uname] it gives me "undefined index" error.

Comment: $_POST['uname] - aren't you missing one `'`? Are you sure your username variable is received too?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

PHP file:

```
<?php
    print_r($_POST);
?>
```

jQuery part:

```
var dataString = 'uname=555';
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url:'check.php',
    data: dataString,

    success: function(data){
        alert(data);//only for testing purposes
    }
});
```

brings me:

[image]

So my only guess would be that you are failing to fetch your data in javascript.

One more idea. Replace the type with `"GET"`. Then in php file write a line:

```
echo $_SERVER["REQUEST_URI"];
```

What does it give you in the alert box? :)

Answer (score 0):

What you send through POST (Either **Ajax** or **non-ajax**) It will be available in a PHP global array called `$_POST`.

To test, place the following in **check.php:**

```
<?php 
print_r($_POST);
?>
```

This should reflect the **Ajax variables** in your `alert()`.